# CSS List Style has random space

Tags: html, css

I am trying to code a page, and for some reason i have a random css spacing issue for my list that i created. On the bottom right i have a random space between the list and its div.

[image]

I am styling it fine i think but my code is here at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/myjDs/8/)

and it works fine there for some reason. Any ideas?

If needed i can supply the entire page link.

I want that whole entire css list to span accross the entire div but it has a huge gap between the left wall of the div and its list.

Comment: I want that whole entire css list to span accross the entire div but it has a huge gap between the left wall of the div and its list.

Comment: The version you have on jsFiddle doesn't have that space, so clearly the styles you've included there are not at fault. In most browsers you can inspect the DOM (with Firebug, Developer Tools, etc). What element do they say is responsible for that spacing?

Comment: I have no idea im using the same exact code on my page, if you want i can link it here.

Comment: You also have in centred in the image you posted, but not in jsfiddle.

Comment: Looks like you need to add `padding: 0` to the appropriate rules for that `ul` element. Also, you shouldn't be using the `center` elements; those are deprecated. Use `text-align: center` in your CSS instead.

Comment: I tried adding `padding: 0` isnt working for me.

Comment: Perhaps the rule you added `padding: 0` to is being overridden. You should use [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) to debug this issue. It makes this kind of thing very easy to debug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The list on the page you link to needs to have its padding (and potentially its margin ... some browsers have different default styles) cleared. Here are some rules you could use to fix this:

```
#navlist {
    list-style-type: none; /* Removes default list style */
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

I highly recommend getting the [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) extension for Firefox. It makes debugging layout issues like this very easy. It also helps you see whether the style rules you are writing are being overridden by a more specific rule elsewhere in your style sheet.

As an aside, you shouldn't be using the `center` element. That element has been deprecated, and should be handled via your style sheet like so: `text-align: center;`